# disadvantage of having multiple triggers on the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple triggers on the same table the reason for using multiple triggers is because there are fields need to be updated from different tables also i have `backward date scheduling`. something wired is going on When i first insert, only one field from one of the triggers updated or one of the trigger fired, when i update row for the first time three trigger fired,... I have to update 3 time to get all fields updated also takes around 8 second every time when i do the first, second, third time updates

question 1. what are the disadvantage of having multiple triggers in the single table?

question 2. How can i speed up triggers?

question 3. how can i debug triggers?

back order Scheduling

> SHIP BY = CUSTOMER PROMISED DATE-1
>
> A-MOUNT BY = SHIP BY -1
>
> A-POWDER BY = A-MOUNT BY - 1 OR A-POWDER BY also equal ship by date -2
>
> A-FAB BY= A-POWDER BY - 1 OR A-FAB BY also equal ship by date -3
>
> A-C/S BY = A-FAB BY OR A-C/S BY also equal ship by date -4
>
> A-CUT BY = A-C/S BY  -1 OR A-CUT BY also equal ship by date -5

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CALC-PROMISED-DATE-AND-SHIPBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CALC-PROMISED-DATE-AND-SHIPBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
    set nocount on
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1
    [SHIP BY] = 
              CASE datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                    WHEN 1 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                    WHEN 7 then DateAdd( day, -1, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                ELSE
                    CASE 
                        WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] =Null THEN ISNULL(T1.[PROMISED DATE],Null)
                         WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] is null THEN ISNULL(T1.[PROMISED DATE],Null)
                    ELSE ISNULL(T1.[RE-COMMIT DATE],Null)
                    END
            END       
            
            FROM WORKORDERS T1
                 INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
                END
```

A-MOUNT BY

```
    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[MOUNTBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:46:54 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MOUNTBY] 
        ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
        AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
        AS 
        BEGIN
         IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
         RETURN
         set datefirst 7;
    UPDATE T1 
        [A-MOUNT BY] = 
        case       datepart(WEEKDAY,  DateAdd(day,-1,t1.[SHIP BY]))
             when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[SHIP BY] )
             when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[SHIP BY] )
            else   DateAdd( day, -1, t1.[SHIP BY] )--t1.[A-C/S BY]-1
        END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-POWDER BY

```
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[POWDERBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:49:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[POWDERBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
--SET
SET [A-POWDER BY] = 
case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-MOUNT BY]-1 )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-MOUNT BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-MOUNT BY])
    else  t1.[A-MOUNT BY]-1 
END

FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-FAB BY

```
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[FABBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:50:23 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FABBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER insert, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
SET [A-FAB BY] =  case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-POWDER BY]-1 )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-POWDER BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-POWDER BY])
    else  t1.[A-POWDER BY]-1 
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

a-PRINT BY

```
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[PRINTBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:50:50 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PRINTBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1
SET [A-PRINT BY] = case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-FAB BY] )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-FAB BY])
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-FAB BY])
    else  t1.[A-FAB BY]-1 
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-C/S BY

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[C/SBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
--SET
SET [A-C/S BY] =  case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-PRINT BY]-1 )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-PRINT BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-PRINT BY])
    else  t1.[A-PRINT BY]-1 
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-CUT BY

```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CUTBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
--SET
SET [A-CUT BY] = 
case       datepart(WEEKDAY,  DateAdd(day,-1,t1.[A-C/S BY]))
     when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-C/S BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-C/S BY] )
    else   t1.[A-C/S BY]-1--t1.[A-C/S BY]-1
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

Comment: Can you post enough of your triggers so they make sense? Are those updates? Are you joining to inserted so you only update the affected rows? Are you aware that you can update more than 1 column in a single update statement? You really need to provide all the information of your issue. This whole things screams of a really poor architecture.

Comment: ok yes but i want to update only a single row or affected rows only

Comment: I get that but you haven't provided any code...only a snippet. When you want to update the affected rows you join to the inserted and/or deleted virtual tables. Present the whole process, not just the part you think is an issue. I can safely say that at this point the whole process is way over complicated. This kind of thing really should not be much more than a single update statement.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange i am editing

Comment: @SeanLange i edited them do it make sense? i am sorry i thought snippets were easier

Comment: See the updates to my answer.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, i tried it but only `SHIP BY` updated

Comment: It is NOT possible that only that one column was updated. The update statement affects multiple columns. Perhaps it only changed the value in that column. I give up. I have no tables to work with, no sample data, no clarity on what this is supposed to do. I have provided a working example that should be 99.999% there.

Answer (score 2):

This is really 3 questions rolled into one post.

**question 1. what are the disadvantage of having multiple triggers in the single table?**

There is no disadvantage here as long as each trigger is for a unique event. It is generally best to avoid having three update triggers on a single table because it is difficult to maintain and sometimes the fire order is important so you would have to manage that as well.

**question 2. How can i speed up triggers?**

There is no catch-all magic button to make triggers go faster. The queries and logic for each trigger needs to be evaluated independently.

**question 3. how can i debug triggers?**

With print statements. Triggers are definitely not easy to debug.

---

This question however lends itself to a larger discussion of triggers. Most of the time triggers are not the best approach to a problem. There are often times better approaches. I have been working with databases for over 2 decades at this point and have had a legitimate need for a trigger only a handful of times. They can be extremely useful for auditing but most of the time they are the wrong tool for the task at hand.

---

Given the new information and code I have created a new trigger that should work for you. You don't need a trigger for each column, you need a trigger for the event of insert and update. You can do all these edits in a single update statement. There still seems to be some major logic issues here but I don't really know what you are trying to do. I would suggest dropping all of those triggers as they very poorly named and given the name they are sort of stuck into a single action.

I would also  highly recommend that you get in the habit of better names. These column names are just dreadful. They shouldn't have spaces, dashes etc.

ALL of those triggers can be simplified to something like this.

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[WORKORDERS_Insert_Update] ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  INSERT, UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN

    set datefirst 7;
    UPDATE T1
        set [SHIP BY] = 
            CASE datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                WHEN 1 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                WHEN 7 then DateAdd( day, -1, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
            ELSE T1.[RE-COMMIT DATE]
                    --CASE This entire case expression is pointless. Just put in the column, all the NULL checks in here are going to do the exact same thing.
                    --    --WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] = Null THEN ISNULL(T1.[PROMISED DATE],Null) Nothing EVER equals NULL. This will never happen
                    --     --WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] is null THEN ISNULL(T1.[PROMISED DATE],Null) ??? Why check for NULL and if it is NULL use an explicit NULL. This makes no sense
                    --ELSE ISNULL(T1.[RE-COMMIT DATE],Null)??? Why check for NULL and if it is NULL use an explicit NULL. This makes no sense
                    --END
            END       
        , [A-MOUNT BY] = 
            case datepart(WEEKDAY,  DateAdd(day,-1,t1.[SHIP BY]))
                when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[SHIP BY] )
                when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[SHIP BY] )
                else DateAdd( day, -1, t1.[SHIP BY] )--t1.[A-C/S BY]-1
            END
        , [A-POWDER BY] = 
            case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-MOUNT BY]-1 )
                when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-MOUNT BY] )
                when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-MOUNT BY])
                else t1.[A-MOUNT BY]-1 
            END
        , [A-FAB BY] = 
            case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-POWDER BY]-1 )
                when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-POWDER BY] )
                when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-POWDER BY])
                else  t1.[A-POWDER BY]-1 
            END
        ,[A-PRINT BY] = 
            case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-FAB BY] )
                when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-FAB BY])
                when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-FAB BY])
                else  t1.[A-FAB BY]-1 
            END
        , [A-C/S BY] = 
            case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-PRINT BY]-1 )
                when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-PRINT BY] )
                when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-PRINT BY])
                else  t1.[A-PRINT BY]-1 
            END
        , [A-CUT BY] = 
            case datepart(WEEKDAY,  DateAdd(day,-1,t1.[A-C/S BY]))
                when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-C/S BY] )
                when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-C/S BY] )
                else   t1.[A-C/S BY]-1--t1.[A-C/S BY]-1
            END
    FROM WORKORDERS T1
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
END
```

Comment: Thank you @Sean How can manage fire orders? In my case i have to update the row three times to get the result i am looking for, how does something like this happens?

Comment: Why do you have to update the same row three times? And why does it take separate triggers?

Comment: I dont have to i was actually just testing trying to figure out why some fields update and some dont and i see that when i update row the triggers fired / fields updated

Comment: The fire order can be set like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql Please note that you can only define first and last. Any other triggers will fire in whatever order the engine decides it wants too and that order is not even always the same.

Comment: Perhaps instead of just guessing at what is going on you could share you trigger code? My guess is there are some other issues going on.

Comment: i edited the `SHIP-BY` fired at the INSERT, the next three `A-MOUNT  BY, A-POWDER BY, A-FAB BY` when updated the row for the first time, `A-C/S BY` on the second update then `CUT BY`

Comment: I do a lot of trigger debugging by creating temp or permanent tables and dumping out inserted/deleted to them (with an added IDENTITY column and a date-time column so I can see when each one ran and order things correctly), along with temp or permanent tables to hold any intermediate results I'm interested in (like from a SELECT).  Sometimes PRINT statements aren't enough. Filling #tempInserted and #tempDeleted let's you manually run trigger SQL against them to test your logic.