# Does sql server trigger has order of execution?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used multiple triggers to implement `backward date scheduling` in Sqlserver using trigger.

But here something wired is going on. here is what i noticed

- `AFTER INSERT`  the following three fields updated `SHIP BY,A-MOUNT BY,A-POWDER BY`
- When i change something to the same record and save `A-FAB` updated
- And for the 2nd time when i change something to the same record and save `A-C\S, A-PRINT BY` updated

**I have to update 3 time to get all fields updated**

Below is the logic on Backward scheduling. All fields are interrelated

> SHIP BY = CUSTOMER PROMISED DATE-1
>
> A-MOUNT BY = SHIP BY -1
>
> A-POWDER BY = A-MOUNT BY - 1 OR A-POWDER BY also equal ship by date -2
>
> A-FAB BY= A-POWDER BY - 1 OR A-FAB BY also equal ship by date -3
>
> A-C/S BY = A-FAB BY OR A-C/S BY also equal ship by date -4
>
> A-CUT BY = A-C/S BY  -1 OR A-CUT BY also equal ship by date -5

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CALC-PROMISED-DATE-AND-SHIPBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:46:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CALC-PROMISED-DATE-AND-SHIPBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
    set nocount on
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1
    [SHIP BY] = 
              CASE datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                    WHEN 1 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                    WHEN 7 then DateAdd( day, -1, t1.[CALC PROMISED DATE])
                ELSE
                    CASE 
                        WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] =Null THEN ISNULL(T1.[PROMISED DATE],Null)
                         WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] is null THEN ISNULL(T1.[PROMISED DATE],Null)
                    ELSE ISNULL(T1.[RE-COMMIT DATE],Null)
                    END
            END       
            
            FROM WORKORDERS T1
                 INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
                END
```

A-MOUNT BY

```
    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[MOUNTBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:46:54 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MOUNTBY] 
        ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
        AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
        AS 
        BEGIN
         IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
         RETURN
         set datefirst 7;
    UPDATE T1 
        [A-MOUNT BY] = 
        case       datepart(WEEKDAY,  DateAdd(day,-1,t1.[SHIP BY]))
             when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[SHIP BY] )
             when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[SHIP BY] )
            else   DateAdd( day, -1, t1.[SHIP BY] )--t1.[A-C/S BY]-1
        END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-POWDER BY

```
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[POWDERBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:49:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[POWDERBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
--SET
SET [A-POWDER BY] = 
case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-MOUNT BY]-1 )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-MOUNT BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-MOUNT BY])
    else  t1.[A-MOUNT BY]-1 
END

FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-FAB BY

```
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[FABBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:50:23 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FABBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER insert, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
SET [A-FAB BY] =  case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-POWDER BY]-1 )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-POWDER BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-POWDER BY])
    else  t1.[A-POWDER BY]-1 
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

a-PRINT BY

```
   /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[PRINTBY]    Script Date: 4/6/2017 2:50:50 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PRINTBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1
SET [A-PRINT BY] = case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-FAB BY] )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-FAB BY])
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-FAB BY])
    else  t1.[A-FAB BY]-1 
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-C/S BY

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[C/SBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
--SET
SET [A-C/S BY] =  case datepart(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-PRINT BY]-1 )
      when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-PRINT BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-PRINT BY])
    else  t1.[A-PRINT BY]-1 
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

A-CUT BY

```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CUTBY] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
     set datefirst 7;
UPDATE T1 
--SET
SET [A-CUT BY] = 
case       datepart(WEEKDAY,  DateAdd(day,-1,t1.[A-C/S BY]))
     when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-C/S BY] )
     when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-C/S BY] )
    else   t1.[A-C/S BY]-1--t1.[A-C/S BY]-1
END
FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    END
```

*I am wondering if its because the ordering if there is any? When i merge all the above trigger to one just the `SHIP BY` field updated all the rest blank set to NUll*

Comment: You have no guaranteed order of execution when you have multiple triggers of the same type (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on the same table. It's possible to specify one of them to be first always, or one of them to be last always, but you can't dictate a full order for any more than that. Your triggers therefore should NEVER depend on the order in which they're run. And frankly, shouldn't operate on the same data.

Comment: We discussed this the other day when I demonstrated how you could combine all of these triggers into a single update statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265377/disadvantage-of-having-multiple-triggers-on-the-same-table

Comment: @SeanLange When i merge all  trigger to one as you suggested  just the SHIP BY field updated all the rest set to blank  or  NULL

Comment: Tips: You might want to try the Sean Lange Merged Trigger and add some code to `RaIsError` or `Throw` an exception if anything winds up unexpectedly NULL. (And toss in a `Rollback` for good measure.) Since the `case` expressions all have `else` clauses the only NULLs would come from your data. Re: Firing order. Typically usage is to use _first_ to validate data (so you don't do anything else with _bad_ data) and _last_ to log to a history table (so you don't log the data and then make more changes). Everything in the middle is just fun and games.

Comment: Well as I said on your previous question on the same topic when you said the trigger doesn't work...it is really difficult to help when we nothing to work with. All we have is the trigger code, not the WorkOrders table or any sample data as basis. In short, we can't test anything because we have nothing to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man - having a lot of triggers on a single table like that...bad juju, I think controlling the execution order is not an approach you want to take. Where there *just have to be* multiple triggers, they should be doing work that doesn't depend on other triggers to do their work first. They should be more completely isolated.

Before we get there, you have expressions that make no sense in your first trigger...things like

```
WHEN t1.[RE-COMMIT DATE] =Null
```

...which you should never see/use when ANSI_NULLS is ON (and which should always be ON).

Also...things like:

```
IsNull( t1.[Promised Date], Null )
```

...make no sense either. This says, return the first value...but if that's null...then return the second value. If you get that stuff out of your trigger, it will be easier to understand.

So...how to get everything in a single trigger? I'd start by making a single trigger...that is sensitive to changes in the promised date(s). After all, everything can be seen as being scheduled based on that. That is, make your trigger as obvious as it can be...and delegate the noisy parts to functions, procedures and views as need.

So, I'd drop all those nasty things and start with something simple, like...

```
create trigger [SetWorkflowDates] on dbo.WORKORDERS for insert, update as
begin

  set nocount on, datefirst 7

  update dbo.WORKORDERS
    set 
      [Ship By]     = dbo.CalcDate('ship',  [Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date]),
      [Mount By]    = dbo.CalcDate('mount', [Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date]),
      [A-Powder By] = dbo.CalcDate('powder',[Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date]),
      [A-Fab By]    = dbo.CalcDate('fab',   [Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date]),
      [A-Print By]  = dbo.CalcDate('print', [Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date]),
      [A-C/S By]    = dbo.CalcDate('cs',    [Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date]),
      [A-Cut By]    = dbo.CalcDate('cut',   [Calc Promised Date],[Promised Date],[Re-Commit Date])
  from
    dbo.WORKORDERS wo
    inner join
    inserted i
    on
      wo.[Work Order #] = i.[Work Order #]
    left outer join
    deleted d
    on
      i.[Work Order #] = d.[Work Order #]
  where
    isnull(i.[Calc Promised Date],getdate()) != 
    isnull(d.[Calc Promised Date],getdate()) 
      or
    isnull(i.[Promised Date],getdate()) != 
    isnull(d.[Promised Date],getdate()) 
      or
    isnull(i.[Re-Commit Date],getdate()) != 
    isnull(d.[Re-Commit Date],getdate())
end
```

Note that this should make the conditions work for insert or update.

Nice and small and clear and *much* easier to debug than a whole bunch of triggers.

So...the trigger won't compile until you define that `CalcDate` function in there...a function that takes governing dates...and computes another date, based on the stage. You're well served to get that out of the trigger itself...just so you can read and understand the trigger without pulling your hair out.

Maybe `CalcDate` might be something like:

```
create function dbo.CalcDate
( 
  @stage varchar(8), @calc date, @prom date, @recommit date 
) 
returns date as
begin

  declare @result date =
    case datepart( weekday, @calc )
      when 7 then 
        dateadd( day, -1, @calc )
      when 1 then 
        dateadd( day, -2, @calc )
      else
        coalesce( @recommit, @prom )
     end

   if ( @stage = 'ship' ) return ( @result );

   set @result = dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @result );       
   if ( @stage = 'mount' ) return ( @result );  

   set @result = dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @result );       
   if ( @stage = 'powder' ) return ( @result ); 

   set @result = dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @result );
   if ( @stage = 'fab' ) return ( @result );       

   set @result = dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @result );
   if ( @stage = 'print' ) return ( @result );

   set @result = dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @result );
   if ( @stage = 'cs' ) return ( @result );

   set @result = dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @result );
   if ( @stage = 'cut' ) return ( @result );

   raiserror( 'Unrecognized stage', 16, 1 );

end
```

So...now I can see that the `CalcDate` calculates a work stage based on the stage...and it's easy to update when the workflow rules change.

...and then finally, the `PreviousWorkDay` function subtracts a day...sees if it's a workday, and if not, subtracts another until it is a work day:

```
create function dbo.PreviousWorkDay( @date date ) returns date as
begin
  set @date = dateadd( day, -1, @date )
  return
  (
    select case datepart( weekday, @date )
      when 7 then dateadd( day, -1, @date )
      when 1 then dateadd( day, -2, @date )
      else @date
    end
  )
end
```

All the code can then make sense - function names say what they do...they don't try to do too much (or not enough). Fixing and updating is much easier. Plan and simplify at every opportunity.

**Note**: You should go delete the earlier question. It just upsets SO folks when you ask questions twice because you didn't like the answers the first time. You won't always get kind treatment when you do that.

Comment: Thank you @clay i get `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SetWorkflowDates, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'.` error  in this line   `wo.[Work Order #] = i.[Work Order #],
    left outer join`

Comment: my bad...there's a comma - I'll fix it - but you have to define the functions first...pretty much in the reverse order that I described 'em. There - I fixed that part of it. No guarantees though...

Comment: Yes that what i am doing,Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much Clay, All looks great only two things 1- `SHIP BY` keeps Sunday's when insert dates works works @update. 2- nest by is `cut-10`

Comment: Okay - so you can mess with the logic on the CalcDate to get exactly what you want. I didn't completely understand your rules from the existing code...but it's probably time of you to experiment until you get exactly what you need, yes?

Comment: how can i implement this on , i want to add some criteria on `print` stage if a field called `[ROUTING]='MO'` `PRINT BY` will be `A-MOUNT-1` WHEN `ROUTING=P&M` `PRINT BY=`A-POWDER-1` WHEN `[ROUTING]='ASSY FD' OR [ROUTING]='WO FD'` A-PRINT= A-FAB-1` OTHERWISE `SHIP BY-20`

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

> The first and last AFTER triggers to be executed on a table can be specified by using sp_settriggerorder. Only one first and one last AFTER trigger for each INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operation can be specified on a table. **If there are other AFTER triggers on the same table, they are randomly executed.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the way all the triggers fires, You can also set the  order of execution for the first and the last trigger. 
So if you have 5 triggers , you can say A will be 1st and E will be last. But C,D and E will be executed randomly.

This post might be helpful

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql